# Deserialize exception from JSON string

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

My WebApi throws an internal server exception, and in the client I'm trying to deserialize back the result in an exception.

The controller's action does:

```
try
{
    //Do something...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return InternalServerError(ex);
}
```

And in the client I'm doing:

```
var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var exception = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Exception>(content);
```

But an exception is thrown:

> Member 'ClassName' was not found.

Checking the context with [Json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com), I get the following objects:

```
public class InnerException
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionType { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionType { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
    public InnerException InnerException { get; set; }
}
```

So where is the `ClassName` coming from, and what is the best way to deserialize an exception?

**EDIT**

To serialize the exception I created a new class derived from `Exception`, and added the following code:

```
    protected RequestException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
    }

    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }
```

However, the original exception details, especially the inner exception, are lost.

Comment: looks that the serialized exception is of derived type, so it has more properties than the type Exception, therefor it cannot be deserialized this way - you must provide exact type of the deserialized exception to the deserializer

Comment: I don't know C# but typically you wouldn't return a raw server-side exception to the front end - since you are catching it, why not return something more user friendly that doesn't expose your class names and server side stack trace?

Comment: can you post your JSON string ?

Comment: what happens when you add `var exception = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourDerivedType>(content);`

Comment: oh, the inner exception can be a problem, if the inner exception is present, deserializer cannot know what type to deserialize it to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not expose exception itself, create your own response object with inner properties, in case of exception fill your own object and pass it to response. on client side use

```
var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResponseObject>(content);
```